# How to transfer files from remote server to local machine when ssh'd in to remote server

Tags: ssh, ftp

I am trying to transfer files from a remote server to my local machine using FTP. I am ssh'd on to the remote server and want to connect to my local machine. The remote server runs on a Linux operating system whereas my local machine runs on a Windows operating system. I know how to transfer files to and from the remote server from my local machine but I am confused as to how to transfer files to and from the local machine from the remote server. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make it look like the remote server pushed/pulled the files? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140396

Comment: I don't need it to look like anything. I was just curious how you would transfer files to your local machine when ssh'd in to the remote server (as opposed to transferring files from the remote server to my local machine when ssh'd in to my local machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to transfer the files when initiating the transfer from your local machine, then just open another window and do it.

I should point out that using FTP for file transfers is insecure.
FTP also doesn't work well with NAT routers.

If your need to initiate the transfer from the remote side, create a reverse tcp tunnel with SSH and use the to connect to your local machine and transfer the files.